# Getting Balance from Subtracting Total Amount from a Number of Balance

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have problem with deducting my balance from a query here is my code:

**Query**

```
select [EmployeeID] = emp.EmployeeID,
    [FullName] = emp.FName + ' ' + emp.LName,
    [LoanTypeID] = lt.LoanTypeID,
    [LoanName] = lt.[Description],
    [Salary] = sal.Amount,
    [TotalLoanAmount] = (
        select SUM(lc1.LoanAmount)
        from LoanContract lc1
        inner join LoanType lt1 on lt1.LoanTypeID = lc1.LoanTypeID
        where lt1.LoanTypeID = lt.LoanTypeID
            and lc1.EmployeeID = emp.EmployeeID
        ),
    [PrincipalAmount] = (
        select ISNULL(SUM((CAST(((lc1.LoanAmount) / ((dbo.fnNumberOfYears(CONVERT(varchar(15), LoanDateStart, 101), CONVERT(varchar(15), LoanPaymentDue, 101)) * 12) * 2)) as decimal(18, 2)))), 0)
        from LoanContract lc1
        inner join LoanType lt1 on lt1.LoanTypeID = lc1.LoanTypeID
        where lt1.LoanTypeID = lt.LoanTypeID
            and lc1.EmployeeID = emp.EmployeeID
        ),
    [Interest] = (
        select ISNULL(SUM((CAST((((lt1.InterestRate / 100) * lc1.LoanAmount) / ((dbo.fnNumberOfYears(CONVERT(varchar(15), LoanDateStart, 101), CONVERT(varchar(15), LoanPaymentDue, 101)) * 12) * 2)) as decimal(18, 2)))), 0)
        from LoanContract lc1
        inner join LoanType lt1 on lt.LoanTypeID = lc1.LoanTypeID
        where lt1.LoanTypeID = lt.LoanTypeID
            and lc1.EmployeeID = emp.EmployeeID
        ),
    [Total] = (
        select ISNULL(SUM((CAST(((((lt1.InterestRate / 100) * lc1.LoanAmount) + lc1.LoanAmount) / ((dbo.fnNumberOfYears(CONVERT(varchar(15), LoanDateStart, 101), CONVERT(varchar(15), LoanPaymentDue, 101)) * 12) * 2)) as decimal(18, 2)))), 0)
        from LoanContract lc1
        inner join LoanType lt1 on lt.LoanTypeID = lc1.LoanTypeID
        where lt1.LoanTypeID = lt.LoanTypeID
            and lc1.EmployeeID = emp.EmployeeID
        ),
    [Balance] = (
        select ISNULL(SUM((CAST(((((lt1.InterestRate / 100) * lc1.LoanAmount) + lc1.LoanAmount) / ((dbo.fnNumberOfYears(CONVERT(varchar(15), LoanDateStart, 101), CONVERT(varchar(15), LoanPaymentDue, 101)) * 12) * 2)) as decimal(18, 2)))), 0)
        from LoanContract lc1
        inner join LoanType lt1 on lt.LoanTypeID = lc1.LoanTypeID
        where lt1.LoanTypeID = lt.LoanTypeID
            and lc1.EmployeeID = emp.EmployeeID
        ),
    [PaymentDate] = lp.DateOfPayment
from Employee emp
inner join Salary sal on sal.EmployeeID = emp.EmployeeID
inner join LoanContract lc on lc.EmployeeID = emp.EmployeeID
inner join LoanPayments lp on lp.LoanID = lc.LoanID
left join LoanType lt on lt.LoanTypeID = lc.LoanTypeID
where lc.EmployeeID in (
        select EmployeeID
        from Employee
        where EmployeeID like case when CAST(ISNULL(@EmployeeID, 0) as varchar(15)) <> 0 then CAST(@EmployeeID as varchar(15)) else '' end + '%'
        )
    and lc.LoanTypeID in (
        select LoanTypeID
        from LoanType
        where LoanTypeID like case when CAST(ISNULL(@LoanType, 0) as varchar(15)) <> 0 then CAST(@LoanType as varchar(15)) else '' end + '%'
        )
    and lp.DateOfPayment between case when ISNULL(@DateStart, '') <> '' then CONVERT(varchar(10), CAST(ISNULL(@DateStart, '') as date), 101) else CONVERT(varchar(10), CAST(ISNULL(GETDATE(), '') as date), 101) end and case when ISNULL(@DateEnd, '') <> '' then CONVERT(varchar(10), CAST(ISNULL(@DateEnd, '') as date), 101) else CONVERT(varchar(10), CAST(ISNULL(GETDATE(), '') as date), 101) end
group by lt.[Description],
    emp.FName,
    emp.LName,
    sal.Amount,
    lp.DateOfPayment,
    emp.EmployeeID,
    lc.LoanTypeID,
    lt.LoanTypeID
order by lp.DateOfPayment,
    emp.FName,
    emp.LName,
    lc.LoanTypeID asc
```

**Result**
[image]

What I am trying to achieve here is that I want to get the total `Balance` column out of how many `Total` column from specific `LoanTypeID`.

For example:
`LoanTypeID = 1, Balance = 6250, TotalLoanAmount = 150,000` since there are 3 `LoanTypeID = 1` then `Balance = 18750` and then finally deducted to the `TotalLoanAmount` so the `Balance` will be `131,250`.

How to achieve this? Can someone help me with this? The only problem is at the `Balance` column.

Comment: you get the payments as a derived table then join to main account and get  total balance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should bring you close to what you need.

```
SELECT
  EP.*,
  LT.Loan_ID,
  LT.Loan_Amount,
  (SELECT
    SUM(amount)
  FROM LoanPayments LP
  WHERE LP.emp_id = EP.emp_id
  AND LP.Loan_id = LT.Load_id)
  [PaymentsPerLoanAccount],
  LT.Loan_Amount - (SELECT
    SUM(amount)
  FROM LoanPayments LP
  WHERE LP.emp_id = EP.emp_id
  AND LP.Loan_id = LT.Load_id)
  [LoanAccountBalance]

FROM employee EP
LEFT OUTER JOIN LoanTable LT
  ON   -- display all employees regardless if there is a loan
  LT.emp_id = EP.emp_id
```